# Is it legal to print pirated pdfs?

Tags: copyright

I mean if someone pirated some books and print them and then sold them to us (without informing us that these books were pirated printed books), is there any lawsuit threatening us?

Answer (score 12):

Your title and your question are totally different.

If someone pirates a book, makes printed copies, and sells them for profit, that's the point where it switches from plain copyright infringement to being *criminal* copyright infringement. Which means jail instead of paying damages is possible.

If you buy one of these printed copies, not knowing that they have been created illegally, and not being willfully ignorant that the printed copies were created illegal, then you didn't commit copyright infringement yourself. Since you are asking the question, it's obvious that you now *know* that there was copyright infringement, and buying any more copies would be encouraging copyright infringement with no excuses for you.

You can be sued for damages. It is unlikely to happen since suing takes likely more effort than getting any damages from you is worth. The correct thing to do is ask the seller for your money back and destroy the copies. If they don't refund your money you can inform the copyright holder.

Comment: Informing the copyright holder should not be contingent upon getting a refund, or any action by the person who sold the OP the unlawful copy of the document. The OP *definitely* should not state any such contingency to the person who sold them the copy. While the refund may be due, it is *very* bad advice to suggest that someone make informing/not informing other people about a potentially criminal act contingent upon receiving something of value (even if they feel it's due). Doing so can *very* quickly result in violating other laws, including, potentially, being a criminal act itself.

Comment: What country criminal code are you refering to?

Comment: Of course if a printed copy is not reasonably mistakable for an "original" (e.g. it is printed with a regular printer on regular paper instead of printed and bound into a proper book), you'd probably have a hard time arguing you didn't know the copy was created illegally. It not taking the same form as an original (specifically when it's lower quality) doesn't *necessarily* mean it was created illegally, but it does almost always mean that.

Comment: What's the answer to the title?

Comment: @Mazura  YES it is illegsl to print pirated PDFs. More exactly, doing so, knowing theist they are pirated is copyright infringement, which can lead to a lawsuit and in some cases to criminal charges.

Comment: NotThatGuy: It is obvious that it is a copy, it is not so obvious that the copy was made illegally.